# Incorrect result in adding date

Tags: javascript, date

```js
r = new Date('Thu Aug 09 2018 22:25:07 GMT+0300');
k = new Date();
k.setDate(r.getDate() + 12);
$('#date_dep').val(k);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="date_dep" />
```

It works fine, but

```js
var r = new Date('Thu Aug 09 2018 22:25:07 GMT+0300');
var k = new Date();
k.setDate(r.getDate() +12);
document.querySelector('#date_dep').value = k;
```

```html
<input id="date_dep" readonly size="40">
```

returns wrong date. 'Thu Aug 09 2018 22:25:07 GMT+0300' is the only way i can get date

http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/120476/

Comment: What do you want to get?

Comment: Tue Aug 21 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300

Comment: Please see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are making a new Date to add days to instead of adding days to the date you created.

```js
r= new Date('Thu Aug 09 2018 22:25:07 GMT+0300');
k=r;//sets k (the date to be changed) to the date you created above
k.setDate(r.getDate() +12);
$('#date_dep').val(k);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="date_dep" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code using moment.js

```
var r = 'Thu Aug 09 2018 22:25:07 GMT+0300';
var d = moment(r);

k=new Date(d.format());
k.setDate(k.getDate() +12);
$('#date_dep').val(k);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/120508/

Comment: This introduces a library and uses the built-in parser twice for no good reason. Posting the code here as a runnable snippet obviates the use of an external site.

Comment: I am usually all for moment/lodash/underscore etc but the majority of the cases on stackOverflow you would have to assume that people are `not` using any 3rd party libs.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this with just one variable. Introducing the `k` causes confusion and leads to the actual issue.

```js
r = new Date('Thu Aug 09 2018 22:25:07 GMT+0300');
r.setDate(r.getDate() +12);
$('#date_dep').val(r);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="date_dep" />
```